# mysql select 3 random rows of each type

Tags: mysql, random

I have created the following query:

```
 SELECT random.aid, random.rand_pid, r3.filepath, r3.filename, r3.pid
 FROM 
 (SELECT r.aid,
    (SELECT r2.pid
     FROM cpg_pictures r2
     WHERE r2.aid = r.aid
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS 'rand_pid'
 FROM cpg_pictures r
 GROUP BY r.aid
 ORDER BY r.aid DESC
 LIMIT 10
 ) random
 LEFT JOIN cpg_pictures AS r3 ON r3.pid = rand_pid
```

cpg_pictures is a table that has pictures
and aid is the album id

this query will get 1 random picture from each album id,

I would like to be able to modify the query so I can get 3 random pictures for each album id,
so any help would be appreciated.

I also would like to join this final result with the cpg_albums table where cpg_pictures.aid = cpg_albums.aid

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 SELECT random.aid, random.rand_pid, r3.filepath, r3.filename, r3.pid
 FROM 
 (SELECT r.aid,
    (SELECT r2.pid
     FROM cpg_pictures r2
     WHERE r2.aid = r.aid
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS 'rand_pid'
 FROM cpg_pictures r
 GROUP BY r.aid
 ORDER BY r.aid DESC
 LIMIT 10
 ) random
 LEFT JOIN cpg_pictures AS r3 ON r3.pid = rand_pid
```

You can also simulate 1 and 2 of this http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10845/return-top-n-rows.aspx